# Qi charging combo for my Google Pixel XL? (Wireless charging)

Tags: wireless-charging, google-pixel

I have been trying to get wireless charging working on my new Google Pixel.  It seems the following combo is a bust...

1. Fone Salesman **UniQi** (receiver) - `Thin Qi Wireless Charging Receiver for USB Type C phones such as Google Pixel, Pixel XL, Nexus 6P, 5X, HTC 10, LG G5, G5 SE, OnePlus 2, 3 (Type-C, USB-C)`

   - http://a.co/cIeimkt
2. Yootech **T500PB** (pad) - `Wireless Charger,Yootech Qi Wireless Charging Pad for Galaxy S7,Galaxy S7 edge, Galaxy S6,Note 5 ,S6 Edge+,S6 Edge, Nexus 4/5/6 and All Qi-Enabled Devices`

   - http://a.co/8tTHQvg
3. Samsung **EP-PG920IBUGUS** (pad) - `Samsung EP-PG920IBUGUS Wireless Charging Pad with 2A Wall Charger- Black Sapphire`

   - http://a.co/5PH84Nf
4. Kroma **5825856** (pad) - `Wireless Charger, Kroma Wireless Charging Pad for Galaxy S7,Galaxy S7 edge, Galaxy S6,Note 5 ,S6 Edge+,S6 Edge, Nexus 4/5/6 and All Qi-Enabled Devices`

   - http://a.co/7zBruMl

I have tried the UniQi receiver with all three charging pads listed above with very little success.  It does show on my phone that it is charging but the phone never increases in stored charge.  For example, went to bed last night with phone at 22% and woke up to a 1% battery life.

Any ideas what combo of Qi receiver and Qi wireless charger that will work with the new Google Pixel XL?

---

Edit: Just bought two of these

- Nillkin **21020107** (receiver) - `Wireless Charging Receiver, Nillkin Magic Tag Type-C Qi Wireless Charger Receiver Chip for Google Pixel/Pixel XL/Nexus 6P/LG V20/Huawei P9/P9 Plus/Honor 8/HTC 10/OnePlus 3 and other USB-C Devices`

  - http://a.co/gq2JGMd

Crossing my fingers and hoping I have better results!